# Does location matters when we call push() to generate keys in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have database reference:

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Is calling

```
databaseRef.push().getKey()    // first
```

different than calling

```
databaseRef.child(<key>).child(<key>).push().getKey()    // second
```

?

Underlying question is as follows: If I inserted a record before using second way and I add a new record using first way, would I be breaking order property of Firebase generated keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First will create a new node to your root, whereas second will create a new node to your specfici location. Basically, push method creates a new node for you by assigning some magical number to it as a key.
Your tree like:

```
-root
   |
    - a
   |
    - b
```

If you call `databaseRef.push()` it will be like:

```
-root
   |
    - a
   |
    - b
   |
    - -KogjXeeIigb6SO-m3Qc
```

Then, if you call `databaseRef.child('b').push()` it will be like:

```
-root
   |
    - a
   |
    - b
      |
       - -Kola-ft7S-atSMBmOhJ
   |
    - -KogjXeeIigb6SO-m3Qc
```

These keys are based on current time so whichever you call last will get the newest time

Comment: I know how it works. My question is about whether the generated number is related to the location or not?

Comment: It is just created according to current time

Comment: You could check there https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: There is more than just the time involved. But you are correct: the generated key does not depend on the location.